# If checkbox is unchecked then remove id from url string?

Tags: jquery, url-rewriting

Below I have a function that when a checkbox is checked it adds the checkbox parents id to the url string, however the issue i'm getting is that when unchecked it doesn't remove the id from the url.

```
var checkboxes = $('.all input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.change(function() {
  var ser = '?' + checkboxes.serialize() + location.hash;
  history.pushState(null, null, ser);
});

$.each(location.search.replace('?', '').split('&'), function(i, seg) {
  $('[name=' + seg.split('=')[0] + ']').attr('checked', 'checked');   

});
```

**Update:** 
There are two of each checkbox parents with the same name, (this is just displaying the info in different ways. (*grid and list view*) So I think the duplicate id numbers in the url string is confusing it.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Try doing `checkboxes.filter(':checked').serialize()`

Comment: I tried that before. It's strange it removes them after one is selected. but won't remove the last id left.

Comment: Any errors in the console when that happens?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you have seems to work without the filter.  Unless I'm missing something.

```js
var checkboxes = $('.all input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.change(function() {
  var ser = '?' + checkboxes.serialize() + location.hash;
  console.log(ser);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="all">
  <input type="checkbox" name="inp1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="inp2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="inp3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the checkboxes are contained in a form the serialize doesn't get all values.

**According to the [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documentation: values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked.**

To solve this you have to serialize by yourself all checkboxes like in:

```js
$(function () {
  var checkboxes = $('.all input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkboxes.change(function(e) {
    var serialized = checkboxes.map(function() {
      return {'name': this.name + this.type, 'value': (this.checked) ? this.value : ' '};
    });
    var ser = '?' + $.param(serialized) + location.hash;
    // history.pushState(null, null, ser);
    $('<p>' +  ser + '</p>').appendTo('body');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form action="demo_form.asp" class="all">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Truck" checked> I have a truck<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Using my loop to serialize you may create different names assembling the name attribute with for instance the element type (this.name+this.tagName)

Comment: can I show you the page, might be easier? the problem is hard to explain.

Comment: @Kez Yes, of course. Remember, this is not a job for me, so my answer may delay